# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validaDocumento' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando criar uma função de validação dentro do ValidationEngine, porém estou recebendo este erro:

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validaDocumento' of undefined***

E Não consigo identificar qual o problema. Tenho outro site utilizando a mesma função, e não consigo ver onde estou errando.

Meu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>Teste</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.0.js"></script>
        <script src="/site/js/script/validationEngine/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
        <script src="/site/js/script/validationEngine/jquery.validationEngine-pt-BR.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $(".validar").validationEngine("attach");
                function validaDocumento(field, rules, i, options){ return true; }
                $(this).submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
            });
        </script>
        <form method="POST" class="validar formConsulta">
            <label>CPF/CNPJ:</label>
            <input type="text" class="validate[funcCall[validaDocumento]]" data-errormessage="Documento invalido!" />
            <input type="submit" value="Consultar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Link para acessar o código: https://codepen.io/maykelesser/pen/zEgovq

Já tentei mudar a ordem do Javascript (colocar em cima, no head, abaixo de tudo, inverter as funções) e sempre dá o mesmo erro.

O que posso fazer para sanar o problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema encontra-se aqui

```
$(function(){
    $(".validar").validationEngine("attach");
        function validaDocumento(field, rules, i, options){ return true; }
            $(this).submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
    });
});
```

O código acima só ira ser executado após a página ser carregada, você está importando os *Scripts*, a página esta sendo renderizada, consequentemente `validate[funcCall[validaDocumento]]` está sendo executado após a importação e antes `$(function(){`, pois o `script` só sera executado quando a página estiver carregada.

Você deve colocar o método `validaDocumento` fora.

```
$(function(){
    $(this).submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
    $(".validar").validationEngine("attach");
});
function validaDocumento(field, rules, i, options){ return true; }
```

### Veja funcionando:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/languages/jquery.validationEngine-pt_BR.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(this).submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
    $(".validar").validationEngine("attach");
});
    function validaDocumento(field, rules, i, options){ return true; }
</script>
<form method="POST" class="validar formConsulta">
    <label>CPF/CNPJ:</label>
    <input type="text" class="validate[funcCall[validaDocumento]]" data-errormessage="Documento invalido!" />
    <input type="submit" value="Consultar">
</form>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Muitíssimo obrigado! Vou aplicar ao código real agora ;-)